# What is the complementary event of 'show' for flex displayobjects

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Since flex memory management is poor, objects once instantiated dont die very easily (even when they go out of scope), one would need to check on various properties of components. I am using one such thing to know if the screen (which is a display object) is in current view. For this I am turning on a boolean property (currently visible), and I am setting it true on show event of the display object.

What I need to know is, which event (something opposite of show, e.g left?) could be used when the screen is replaced by another display object?

Something like focusIn and focusOut from dotnet.

Or if there is some property which could directly tell me if the display object is currently in view (hasFocus doesnt seem to be giving me expected results).

Thanks.

Comment: Is [FocusIn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:focusIn)/[FocusOut](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:focusOut) events what you are looking for? Though, these events can trigger even if the object is still on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the event is: removedFromStage.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use PropertyChageEvent check the documentation and base of the newValue and kind property you can do some action :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/PropertyChangeEvent.html

hope this help